# How to disable charging *from* the tablet?

Tags: usb, charging

Usually you plug tablet/phone in order to charge that tablet/phone.

I have peculiar problem with "reverse" setup -- I have a keyboard (digital piano) plugged in to the wall socket, then I use MIDI-USB converter to connect to the tablet via USB (so MIDI on the keyboard side, USB on the tablet side). And on the connection somehow tablet gets the idea it needs to charge the keyboard.

Of course it does not make sense, but drains the tablet battery pretty quickly.

So my question is how to disable charging **from** the tablet?

*If this matters: tablet is Samsung TAB S6 LITE SM-P610*.

Comment: Where does the MIDI-USB converter get it's power from? Can it get the power from MIDI side? Because if not the USB side is the only option to power it. Assuming the MIDI-USB adapter has no battery then "charging" means simply that the tablet provides the necessary power to the adapter. The only thing you can try is placing an active hub in between so the hub powers the USB-MIDI adapter.

Comment: @Robert, I always assumed it is a passive element, basically like a cable. Good catch, thank you very much.